# Proof that a sequence defines a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cauchy-sequences

I recently did a question that said to prove the sequence ${\{x_n\}}=\frac{3n}{2n+1}$ is Cauchy and I'm unsure on if my proof is valid.

First I stated that ${\{x_n\}}$ is Cauchy $\iff \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t: $|x_n-x_m| < \epsilon, \forall m,n \ge N$

I then did the following calculations:
Consider the quantity $|x_n-x_m|=\left|\frac{3n}{2n+1}-\frac{3m}{2m+1}\right| = \left|\frac{3n}{(2n+1)(2m+1)} + \frac{-3m}{(2n+1)(2m+1)}\right| \le \frac{3n}{(2n+1)(2m+1)} + \frac{3m}{(2m+1)(2n+1)} < \frac{3}{2m+1} + \frac{3}{2n+1}$

I then stated that we wanted to choose a value for $N$ such that
$|x_n-x_m| < \frac{3}{2m+1}+\frac{3}{2n+1} < \epsilon + \epsilon = 2\epsilon$

Therefore, if we let $\frac{3}{2m+1}<\epsilon$, we can rearrange to obtain $m > \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{\epsilon}\right)-1$

Therefore, choose $N=\left\lceil\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{\epsilon}\right)-1\right\rceil\square$

I'm very new to real analysis so I don't have a full grasp on the required levels of formality just yet, so any tips or pointers would be appreciated :)

Comment: $|\frac{3n}{2n+1} - \frac{3m}{2m+1}| = |\frac{3n}{(2n+1)(2m+1)} + \frac{-3m}{(2n+1)(2m+1)}|$ I think this is false, I think that you forgot to expand this term using MCM.

Comment: @geetha290krm and Daniel C, please forgive me if I am wrong. I cannot see where the OP's reasoning goes wrong.

Comment: @DanielC. OP is correct. It's just that some calculations are skipped. The $6mn$ terms cancelled out.

Comment: Sorry then, I didn't notice that cancellation

Comment: When typing out the post I omitted some of the algebra when dealing with the fractions

Comment: Your definition of Cauchy looks good, and technique of proof looks good. If I was marking this I would give full marks (assuming the algebra is correct).

Comment: I would say that this kind of writing is bad. Cancellation should have been shown.

Comment: Sorry but I'm extremely slow at typing out Latex, so I skimmed over a lot of the steps I'd written down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof looks fine,
but I suggest beginners follow the definition pedantically.
The statement to show, as you stated, is:
$$
\forall \varepsilon>0\ \exists N\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall m,n>N:|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon
$$
If we strictly follow this definition,
we'll notice that any proof should end with $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$.
What you have written, strictly speaking, is only a draft which helps you find the $N$.
You didn't show us that this choice of $N$ actually works (you demonstrated a *motivation* why it would work).
In fact, your $N$ could be zero if $\varepsilon$ is large enough,
so you probably cannot turn your draft into the actual proof directly.

For example, you could write something like this:

> Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $N=\lceil \frac{3}{2\varepsilon}-1 \rceil$. Note that $N\ge 0$, so $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $m,n>N$. Then ... Therefore, $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$.

Another thing is that you can choose a simpler $N$ (not necessarily an explicit expression).
Note that if $m>N>0$, then
$$
\frac{3}{2m+1}<\frac{3}{m}<\frac{3}{N}.
$$
You would get a simpler explicit expression for $N$ if you did a little more simplification of the inequality like above.
However, you can avoid an expression of $N$ at all by saying that "by Archimeandean principle, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\frac{\varepsilon}{6}$."
The expression does not actually matter in this case
because it is only used to guarantee that $\frac{3}{N}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$,
so you don't need to construct it explicitly.

Hope this helps!